# QGIS 3.28.5 can't open a project file

Tags: qgis-3, save, qgz

Do you know any solution? I think in similar cases I could unzip the .qgz file and then I was opening the .qgs file but I can't do it with this project. I saw other answers, the file is there for months, I haven't moved it.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried manually unzipping it? Have you made sure the path isn't too long?

Comment: With 7zip and windows zip. The path is the same for all my projects, why others don't create problem? The last part? But when I was working it, it was opening normaly, I had to check it after 2 months and it looks corrupted. I don't remember to change the Qgis version, they have that ltr for a long time.

Comment: What, exactly, prevents you from unzipping it manually and opening the .qgs? Does 7zip / win-zip fail too? Or do they work, but QGIS won't open the .qgs anyway? Can you share the project file (without any data)? Also, QGIS is backward compatible for project files, I opened 1.8 version projects with 3.2x version of software; so updating shouldn't be a problem,